# How to know the output of a previous command in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>result.txt (
  for /f %%a in (srvrname.txt) do (
   ping -n 1 %%a > nul && echo %%a up||echo %%a DOWN 
))
```

I was doing a ping test for some servers with the above script. I want to understand how the output of the ping command is passed to echo UP or echo DOWN section..As in unix we have $? to  know if the previous command executed successfully like if[$? -eq 0] then; do success else failure done.
How does this happen in a batch script. DO WE HAVE A VARIABLE like $? in batch. Please let me know. Also please suggest if we could make the pingtest script any better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `%errorlevel%`.

This will give you the error code for the last command that executed.

```
if %errorlevel%==0 echo SUCCESS
if %errorlevel%==1 echo FAIL
```

***Note:*** There is a whole range of errorcodes that could be set, I just used 1 as an example, check the command documentation to find the errorcode's meaning.

Beware though, if you are using `%errorlevel%` in your `for` loop you will need to use delayed expansion.

You already have it added on your script (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`), so you just need to change the `%`'s to `!`'s.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>result.txt (
  for /f %%a in (srvrname.txt) do (
   ping -n 1 %%a > nul
   if !errorlevel!==0 (
   echo Ping replied successfully
   ) else (
   echo There was an error
   )
))
```

Comment: I think the line ping -n 1 %%a > nul && echo %%a up||echo %%a DOWN would become ping -n 1 %%a > nul. as i am verifying using the errorlevel now. Please let me know if i am right. Thanks a lot for your response.that cleared some of my doubts

Comment: Yeah it would, I almost took that bit of myself from my answer as it wouldn't make sense, but I left it on as it was in your OP. I have taken it off now :)

Comment: I would like to know when i am not using ERRORLEVEl, how does my output of ping command pass to the other section ping -n 1 %%a > nul && echo %%a up||echo %%a DOWN. as here i have not used the pipe operator.so how echo up or down is printed.

Comment: The left side of the pipe is success and the right side is fail.